# Sticky navigation bar -React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation

I am currently working on making a portfolio. I want to have a navigation bar on the top. Once you click on a tab on the navigation bar, it will scroll you down to that particular page and the navigation bar will stick on the top. I am currently using react-scroll. However, I need suggestions on how I can make the navigation bar stick on the top while scrolling down. 
Right now, my code looks something like this:

```
import { Link} from "react-scroll";
class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section id="nav-bar">
        <nav className="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div className="navbar">
            <ul
            >
              <li>
                <Link
                  activeClass="active"
                  to="home"
                  spy={true}
                  smooth={true}
                  offset={-70}
                  duration={500}
                >
                  Home
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link
                  activeClass="active"
                  to="demo"
                  spy={true}
                  smooth={true}
                  offset={0}
                  duration={500}
                >
                  Demo
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link
                  activeClass="active"
                  to="process"
                  spy={true}
                  smooth={true}
                  offset={-70}
                  duration={500}
                >
                  Process
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

In my App.js I only return all the pages in a div

```
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <HomePage />
        <DemoPage />
        <ProcessPage />
      </div>
```

Will appreciate any type of help or suggestion. Should I use anything else other than react-scoll?. Thanks!

Comment: check this link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp .. maybe you will find an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-scroll` has a `Element` class, you should wrap you component whit Element

```
<Element name="home">
          <HomePage />
        </Element>
```

Here is the temporary [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-scroll-g1e10) containing the fixed version

Comment: Hi, maybe I wasn't very clear with my question. My code works exactly the way you have shown in your sandbox example. But I want the navigation bar stick on the top when it scrolls down for instance to ProcessPage.

Comment: I've added `.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(224, 197, 252, 0.637);
}` to css and changed `offset ` props of `Link`.you should change the `offset `with your appropriate values. please check it out.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem. The content of a page hides the navigation bar on scroll. Check out: [picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FmN1XkxfDSPXylLJ75DoeW7iagTqBSlJ/view?usp=sharing)

I am trying to make something like [this](http://fisshy.github.io/react-scroll-example/basic/index.html). But I am not sure how to do it!

Comment: As I mentioned , you should change the offset with your appropriate values.if its possible put your code in the sandbox

Comment: Yes, I added offset as -70. I am not that familiar to sandbox. I have my code in [Github repo](https://github.com/nahidaislam/Disasteroid-website/tree/master/disasteroid/src/Components/Navbar). Have been debugging for hours without any luck

Comment: I think I found out what the problem is. I am using **cards** from **react-bootstrap**, which for some reason gets on top of the navigation bar on scroll. I tried with **cards** from **material UI** and it works fine.

Comment: For your question my solution worked fine, you haven't mentioned using react-bootstrap

Comment: My bad. I didn't know that was the problem. Thanks for helping anyway.